# Validating a list using Regex

Tags: regex

I have been asked to help sort out a system that validates some returned MS Excel forms.

A Python program already exists that takes a returned Excel form, and another MS Excel workbook with looks much like the form, but the fields are filled with Regexes.

The Python code then validates the form by testing  the returned form, against the Regexes in turn from the Regex form.

This all works as expected, and pumps out a workbook with a list of problems where a match doesn't occur.

However the validation wasn't always returning results as expected and I was asked to try sorting it out.

I have been reviewing the regexes against a document describes what the valid responses in the form should be. I can cope with most of them, but a couple of them got me to thinking. These are ones where the valid entry in the form is a list of items. E.g. a list of words seperated by commas or newlines.

Everytime I come across one of these I have been using the following approach:

```
^[A-Z]{0,10}((, *|\n)[A-Z]{0,10})*$
```

So this will match the first uppercase word up to 10 letters, then the rest of the list with each entry preceeded by a `,` or `<CR>`. It works, but I wonder if there is a better way? The reason I am thinking this is because the matching pattern for each list entry has to be in the regex twice. So if a problem is spotted, it has to be corrected in two places.

Is there a better way?

Comment: It is correct and the best way. If you do not want to repeat the same twice, define the `[A-Z]{0,10}` as a variable, and build the pattern dynamically.

Comment: You could have the pattern only once by using `^((^|, *|\n)[A-Z]{0,10})*$`.

Comment: I like that @ClasG. Kind of obvious now I think about it.

Comment: @SRMoll However, that is wrong. It will allow a string like `,`. Or `",     "`

Comment: You can match "comma or start of string" like this `^((,|^)<pattern>)+$`

Comment: @Tezra This pattern has the same flaw as ClasG's. It allows the delimiter at the start of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you give an example where it fails? all my tests pass. (I added a missing char)

Comment: @Tezra What are your tests?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew https://regex101.com/r/jUnngD/1. Since the pattern allows empty, `,,AZ` is valid. But changing the pattern to {1,10} changes that. I can't find any example that is invalid for the pattern.

Comment: Hmm! Why doesn't that work?

Comment: In my opinion, `,AA,AAA` is invalid.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The empty string matches the pattern `[A-Z]{0,10}`, therefor it has to be valid. This is a complaint about the pattern though. You should probably use `{1,10}` in the pattern, and make the outer loop `*`, but that depends on what kind of list to accept.

Comment: @Tezra A pattern that has an infinitely quantified group containing two atoms one of them being optional is never a good idea (well, unless that group is the last subpattern in the pattern). It is just bad practice in regex, and I am against that.

Comment: I would like it to accept:  
ABCDE, FGHI, JKLMN  
But not:  
,ABCDE, FGHI, JKLMN  

Or multiple commas without detail between them.

Comment: A new try - `^(?=\w)((^|, *|\n)[A-Z]{1,10})+$`. It isn't as "elegant" as the first (which obviously should have been `^((^|, *|\n)[A-Z]{1,10})+$`), since in a way a repetition is made.

Comment: That appears to work @ClasG

Comment: Well I'm certainly learning lots over the last few days. Not really messed around with regex much before. Got some really nasty looking ones to sort out, but I'm going to ponder them for a bit more first.

Comment: is this a [tag:python] question?

Comment: No @C8H10N4O2. There is a Python program that is processing the Excel workbook with the regexes I am working on. So it is only pertinent in defining which engine will be processing the regexes if it makes a difference to anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
^\b((^|, *|\n)[A-Z]{1,10})+$
```

It makes sure the text starts with a *word character* (i.e. `a-zA-Z0-9_`) by checking for a word boundary. Thus preventing the text to start with `,` or an empty line.

Then, repeating at least once, there should be a line beginning with one of

- Start of text
- A comma followed by any number of spaces
- a newline

then, at least one, at the most ten, uppercase characters.

The first start alternative is obviously only possible for the start of the line, the second for intermediate words and the final for the last word on a line.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/79mKbp/1).

Comment: I would replace the look-ahead with a simple boundary check `\b` or use anything not your delimiter `[^,\n]` instead of `\w`

Comment: Good one @Tezra. I agree. It makes it better. Edited.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll give it a try on the next field with a list. Got a different problem at the moment.